# Issues with file ownership after git push

Tags: linux, permissions, git

I have a server at home running Ubuntu 13.10 configured as webserver and git repository. If I push my project from my system to the server a post-receive hook is executed that moves the files (Symfony2 project) to the correct virtual server's web root.

Part of the reason I'm doing this (hosting my own server) is because I want to learn more about the best practices in server hosting.

I push to my git server through SSH as user git who has permission to the git repositories in /opt/git (some guide recommended doing it this way). The shell for the git user is set to /usr/bin/git-shell.

My webserver is nginx running as user 'www-data' I believe this is the default setup since I didn't configure this.

The problem I have right now is that after deploying the www-data user and my own user (tim) don't have permission to write to the cache directory resulting in Symfony crashing.

The reason why my user (tim) is involved is because the project has a cronjob that I set up in my own user account, which might not be the best idea ever.

Also for some reason the default permissions for the cache/ directory after a commit are

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 git git  4096 Jul 29 09:33 cache
```

So to the best of my knowledge that means only the git user is allowed to create files/directories inside the cache folder.

Now I can think of 101 ways to handle this issue, but I'm more interested in a correct/intended way to solve my problem.

- Should I in some way chown the files to the www-data user and run the cronjobs as the same user?

  - This seems complicated because I don't think the git user is allowed to "give files to someone else"
- Should I find a way to run the post-receive hook as a different user www-data or tim?
- As which user should my cronjob run? Can it just be tim? or should it be the www-data user? (or god forbid root)

This is the content of my post-receive script (I found it on some website can't remember which one)

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
## store the arguments given to the script
read oldrev newrev refname

## Where to store the log information about the updates
LOGFILE=./post-receive.log

# The deployed directory (the running site)
DEPLOYDIR=/var/www/project.timfennis.com

##  Record the fact that the push has been received
echo -e "Received Push Request at $( date +%F )" >> $LOGFILE
echo " - Old SHA: $oldrev New SHA: $newrev Branch Name: $refname" >> $LOGFILE

## Update the deployed copy
echo "Starting Deploy" >> $LOGFILE

echo " - Starting code update"
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout -f
echo " - Finished code update"

echo " - Starting composer update"
cd "$DEPLOYDIR"; composer update; cd -
echo " - Finished composer update"

echo "Finished Deploy" >> $LOGFILE
```

I'm pretty sure composer is the one resetting my file permissions to 755 because the cache dir is deleted every time.